Биос с открытым исходным кодом или же написание своего кастомного биоса
Я сейчас занимаюсь созданием кастомного телефона на x86 процессоре, делаю свою печатную плату и прекрасно знаком с содержимым устройства на основе которого делаю телефон это Lenovo Ideapad 5 15ALC05 и вот что в нём стоят за комплектующие: процессор: ryzen 7 5700u, мультиконтроллер: IT8227E-128, флешка биоса: W74M12JWSSIQ
Мне нужно что бы работали все порты и не было ограничений на то какие устройства я буду подключать(к примеру если в ноут воткнуть не родной вайфайник то он может начать жаловаться на это).
За надобностью я могу заменить комплектующие по скольку печатную плату я делаю кастомную и поставить туда могу что угодно. Мне нужен либо гайд как вообщем делать биос для платформы FP6, либо открытый код биоса для платформы FP6. Буду очень благодарен любой ссылке на гайд или вовсе на биос с открытым исходным кодом
